# Sample Mean and Sample Variance Unbiased Estimators For Any Distribution?

Tags: variance, expected-value

It's commonly known that the sample mean

$$
\bar{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n}
$$

and the sample variance

$$
s^2 = \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n - 1}
$$

are unbiased estimators of the population mean and variance.  I have always thought of $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$ as unbiased estimators only for the parameters of a normal distribution $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. My question is are $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$ unbiased estimators for population expected value and population variance for any distribution?

For example, suppose you have a random sample from a gamma distribution and you calculate $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$. Let $X$ be a gamma distributed random variable with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\theta$. Can we expect $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bar{x} = E[X] = k\theta$$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}s^2 = \text{Var}[X] = k\theta^2$$ will hold true for a gamma distribution. If this is true for the gamma example, is it also true for the expected value and variance of any distribution? If so, why?

Lastly, if this is true, does it eliminate the need for maximum likelihood estimators when the distribution parameters you are trying to estimate also happen to be the expected value and variance of the distribution (i.e. normal distribution)?

Comment: So long as the population mean and variance are finite, your $\bar x$ and $s^2$ are unbiased estimators.  But they may not be the best estimators.  Try a uniform distribution on unknown $[a,b]$ as an example

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)?